# Duda con un mapper: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo un mapper que recibe un Json de una API externa de un cliente.
Hasta ahora no entiendo donde esta el problema en mi mapeo de mis POJOS:

JSON:

```
{
"request": {
    "Target": "Affiliate_Offer",
    "Format": "json",
    "Service": "HasOffers",
    "Version": "2",
    "api_key": "5a69f5ffcf184b1360d",
    "Method": "findAll",
    "contain": [
        "Country"
    ]
},
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
        "18239": {
            "Offer": {
                "id": "18239",
                "name": "Clinical Trial: Major Depressive Disorder",
                "approval_status": "approved"
            },
            "Country": {
                "US": {
                    "id": "840",
                    "code": "US",
                    "name": "United States",
                    "regions": {
                        "4": {
                            "id": "4",
                            "country_code": "US",
                            "country_code_3c": "USA",
                            "code": "AR",
                            "name": "Arkansas"
                        },
                        "5": {
                            "id": "5",
                            "country_code": "US",
                            "country_code_3c": "USA",
                            "code": "CA",
                            "name": "California"
                        },
                        "51": {
                            "id": "51",
                            "country_code": "US",
                            "country_code_3c": "USA",
                            "code": "WY",
                            "name": "Wyoming"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "18865": {
            "Offer": {
                "id": "18865",
                "name": "Dragon Circle Community - US, UK, CA, AU, NZ",
                "approval_status": null
            },
            "Country": {
                "US": {
                    "id": "840",
                    "code": "US",
                    "name": "United States",
                    "regions": []
                },
                "UK": {
                    "id": "826",
                    "code": "UK",
                    "name": "United Kingdom",
                    "regions": []
                },
                "AU": {
                    "id": "36",
                    "code": "AU",
                    "name": "Australia",
                    "regions": []
                },
                "CA": {
                    "id": "124",
                    "code": "CA",
                    "name": "Canada",
                    "regions": []
                },
                "NZ": {
                    "id": "554",
                    "code": "NZ",
                    "name": "New Zealand",
                    "regions": []
                }
            }

        },
        "errors": [],
        "errorMessage": null
    }
}
```

}

Esta es la estructura que he creado para hacer el mapeo:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OfferMapper {
   OfferRequest request;
   OfferResponse response;
}

@Getter @Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OfferResponse {
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private int status;
    @JsonProperty("httpStatus")
    private int httpStatus;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Map<String, OfferData> data;
}
```

Aqui esta el problema al poner el Country:

```
@Getter @Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OfferData {
   @JsonProperty("Offer")
   private Offer offer;

   @JsonProperty("Country")
   private CountryMapper country;
```

}

Aqui esta el Country Mapper:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CountryMapper {
    private Map<String, CountryData> countries;
}
```

Country Data:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CountryData {
   @JsonProperty("id")
   private int id;
   @JsonProperty("code")
   private String code;
   @JsonProperty("name")
   private String name;
   @JsonProperty("regions")
   private List<RegionDto> regions;
}
```

Si comento el CountryMapper ya tengo toda la estructura de request y response mapeada:

```
{
"request": {
    "Target": "Affiliate_Offer",
    "Format": "json",
    "Service": "HasOffers",
    "Version": "2",
    "api_key": "5a69d35838cf8466f8fcf184b1360d",
    "Method": "findAll",
    "contain": [
        "Country"
    ]
},
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
        "18239": {
            "country": null,
            "Offer": {
                "id": "18239",
                "name": "Clinical Trial: Major Depressive Disorder",
                "approval_status": "approved"
            }
        },
        "18865": {
            "country": null,
            "Offer": {
                "id": "18865",
                "name": "Dragon Circle Community - US, UK, CA, AU, NZ",
                "approval_status": null
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Por lo que estoy entendiendo el mapper esta esperando un Array pero al menos para mi la respuesta no es un array. He probado tranformar en una List pero tambien no funciona. He hablado con algunos companeros que tambien estan de acurdo que este JSON no es ideal deberia haber una estructura de array [ ]. Tambien que de esta manera parece que teria que crear un objeto para cada pais que tambien no seria una buena opcion. Asi que cualquier sugerencia seria de granayuda que estoy a un par de dias buscando entender eso.

Comment: El problema es que `regions` arriba es un objeto y después es un array. No hay consistencia en los datos, es por ello que te lanza el error.

Comment: Si no sabes lo que vas a recibir, puedes declarar el tipo de `regions` como `JsonNode`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez creo que no es ahi, porque ni llega al punto de mapeo de las regions. Igualmente lo tengo mapeado tambien, he editado mi pregunta y anadido la parte con las regions. Si que es verdad que el problema es que no sabe lo que tiene que recibir si un objeto o una lista.